signature verification failed
I'm trying to upgrade  from 22.04.5 LTS to 24 LTS.
The command
sudo apt-get update
issues a signature problem (see below), and this prevents the release upgrade.
How can I fix it?
=========================================
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [129 kB]
Err:5 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/npreining:/debian-ubuntu-onedrive/xUbuntu_22.04 ./ InRelease
The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG B8AC39B0876D807E home:npreining OBS Project home:npreining@build.opensuse.org
Fetched 131 kB in 1s (147 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/npreining:/debian-ubuntu-onedrive/xUbuntu_22.04 ./ InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG B8AC39B0876D807E home:npreining OBS Project home:npreining@build.opensuse.org
W: Failed to fetch https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/npreining:/debian-ubuntu-onedrive/xUbuntu_22.04/./InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG B8AC39B0876D807E home:npreining OBS Project home:npreining@build.opensuse.org
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Please read https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/discussions/2774 on how to solve this particular issue.
